# How would I prompt the user to fill in [x] variables based on the value of x they entered in the previous prompt in python?

Tags: python, variables

## variables

```
free_time = (int)input("How much free time do you have? ->").strip()
num_activties = (int)input("How many activities would you like to spend your free time on? ->").strip()
```

How would I go about asking the user to fill out x amount of variables based on the number they input in `num_activies`?

Comment: Try using a `for` or `while` loop that iterates `num_activities` times and appends to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the user would always input a number,
do like this:

```
answers = []
num_activities = int(input("How many activities would you like to spend your free time on? ->"))

for time in range(num_activities):
    answer = input("Question: ")
    answers.append(answer)
```

Then you can access the questions with the `answers` variable

Like, to print the n-th answer: `print(answers[n])`